# How to take multiple input in a same readline.question and store in different variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, command-line-interface, readline

So I want to ask multiple input from a user in a same readline.question and wanted to store it into different variable but i'm facing the problem i don't know how i can do that.
**Code**

```
import * as readline from 'node:readline';
function askQuestion(query) {
const io = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
    terminal: false
});
return new Promise(resolve => io.question(query, ans => {
    resolve(ans);
}));
}

let numRows;
let numCols;
let winLength;
numRows = await askQuestion("Please enter the rows number ");
numCols = await askQuestion("Please enter the columns number ");
winLength = await askQuestion("Please enter the win length ");
```

**Example**

```
numRows, numCols, winLength = await askQuestion(`Please enter${numRows}x${numCols} = ${winLength}`);
```

i wanted to do like this but this is not working.

**Another Thing i'm facing is that after it asked many question, i got memory leak error in terminal**

```
(node:7220) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 end listeners added to [ReadStream]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

anyone can solve this memory leak error?

Comment: The job will be to assign that input to a single string variable, parse that string, converting tokens to ints, checking syntax and handling errors. Coding that depends on  input format requested of the user. Please add that to the question

Comment: Do not create for every question a new "readline.createInterface". It assigns by ever call a new event listener to the provided streams which results in the EE leak.

Comment: "I want to ask multiple input from a user in a same readline.question" You need to parse the answer then. Check if the answer has your desired format "${numRows}x${numCols} = ${winLength}" and extract these values.

Answer (score 0):

why not close Readline?

```
io.close();
resolve(ans);
```

Comment: Thank you! it's fixed the memory leak error but can you help with the primary problem?